# BoxWhiskerPlot grouped: matching colors of outliers, whiskers, etc

Tags: charts

**How to be able to make whiskers and fences of red boxes red, and of blue boxes blue in the following example with grouped boxplots?**

````
xdata = {{"A", {1, 2, 5}}, {"B", {5, 7, 2, 2, 5}}, {"C", {3, 2, 5, 7}}};
ydata = {{"A", {7, 2}}, {"B", {7, 2, 5}}, {"C", {6, 7, 3}}};

labels = {xdata[[All, 1]], None}

xdata = xdata[[All, 2]];
ydata = ydata[[All, 2]];

data = Transpose@{xdata, ydata}

style = Sequence[{
  {"Whiskers", Dashed},
  {"Outliers", None},
  {"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thick, White]}},
  ChartStyle -> {Red,BLue},
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  ChartLegends -> {"x", "y"},
  ChartLabels -> labels];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, style]
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can post-process `BoxWhiskerChart` output to remove the default fence and whisker colors:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, style] /. g_GraphicsGroup :> (g /. GrayLevel[Except[1]] -> {})
```

[image]

***Note:*** In versions 11.3.0 and older, replace `g_GraphicsGroup` with `g_GraphicsGroupBox`.

**2.** Alternatively, you can add a custom `ChartElementFunction` to `style` as follows:

```
style2 = Sequence[{{"Whiskers", Dashed}, {"Outliers", None}, 
    {"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thick, White]}}, 
   ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   ChartLegends -> {"x", "y"}, ChartLabels -> labels, 
   ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementData["BoxWhisker"][##] /. 
     GrayLevel[Except[1]] -> {} &)];

BoxWhiskerChart[data, style2]
```

[image]

Use `ChartStyle -> "Rainbow"` instead of `ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}` to get

[image]