# Formatting BoxWhiskerChart: rotate label, remove extra ticks, center legend

Tags: plotting, labeling, spacing

I am having a problem with a couple of things in this grouped box chart.
Using following data I can plot a grouped box-whisker chart [(example)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242078/boxwhiskerplot-grouped-matching-colors-of-outliers-whis):

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = {{"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"}, None};
xdata = RandomReal[10, {5, 5}];
SeedRandom[2];
ydata = RandomReal[10, {5, 5}];
Transpose[{xdata, ydata}];
BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartLabels -> labels, ImageSize -> 500];
```

[image: annotated output with requested changes]

Here, yellow and blue form one group, and there are 5 groups in total.  I would like to

1. Reduce the ingroup spacing and increase the inter-group spacing.
2. Rotate the axis label by 45 deg
3. Remove two extra ticks and put one tick for the group.
4. Common bottom label (like treatment in the ref fig below)

Something like this with rotated labels:
[image: example of desired output]

Comment: 1. look at the `BarSpacing` option for BoxWhiskerChart. 2. Look up [`Rotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html). 3. I seem to remember that this has been discussed before here, but I couldn't immediately find it. 4. You may want to create your own legend with [`SwatchLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SwatchLegend.html) and then maybe enclose the chart and legend in [`Framed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html).

Comment: Thanks Marco, I was able to do 1, 2 and 4 will be probably easy using frame.